# Validating parameters in constructor

Tags: php, oop

I'm developing a library management system, and basically I have an abstract class "Reader" that extends to "students, teachers and people in general". My question is, I have a class "Requests" and I need to know which "Reader" request the book, to be able to validate this data:

"teachers can only request 10 books simultaneously,  the students can only request 5 books in simultaneously and the public in general can oly request 2 books in simultaneously;"

"teachers can keep each book at maximum for 6 months, students for 5 days, and the general public for 1 month;"

"if a teacher has a book for more than three months and there is a need to request it, the teacher must be notified to return the book;"

How can I pass the three type of "Readers" in the __construct, to validate the above data.

```
class Requests
{
    protected $bookRequested;
    protected $teacher;
    protected $student;
    protected $public;
    protected $requestDate;
    protected $returnDate;

    public function __construct(Book $bookRequested, Teacher $teacher, Student $student, GeneralPublic $public)
    {
        $this->bookRequested = $bookRequested;
        $this->teacher = $teacher;
        $this->student = $student;
        $this->public = $public;
        $this->requestDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $this->returnDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }
}
```

Comment: Use interface. Then check instanceof

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need all three readers in same request, since only one of them is going to be involved in a given transaction. If you have this:

```
abstract class Reader {}
class Teacher extends Reader {}
class Student extends Reader {}
class GeneralPublic extends Reader {}
```

... then your constructor just needs one parameter, the base class:

```
public function __construct(Book $bookRequested, Reader $reader) {}
```

To configure stuff you can just create a property or method. If you opt for a method you get the plus of being able to make it abstract too:

```
abstract class Reader
{ 
    abstract public function getMaxBooks();
}

class Teacher extends Reader
{
    public function getMaxBooks() {
        return 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, ok i got it now, :), and what about the date, how can i build a function to display the date that a "Reader" requested a book, and the date that a "Reader" need to return the book, based on this rule: "teachers can keep each book at maximum for 6 months, students for 5 days, and the general public for 1 month". I've already tried some solutions, but none of them worked :(

Comment: Isn't it exactly the same problem? Create an abstract `getDueDate()` method and implement it in every child class. (Unless you're asking how to do date maths in PHP, which is of course a different subject.)

Answer (score 0):

i hope if i can help with that you can check on class type when validate.

```
class Reader{
    protected $requests;
    protected $name;
    public function get_name(){
        return $this->name;
    }
}
class Teacher extends Reader{

}
class Student extends Reader{

}
 class GeneralPublic extends Reader{

 }
 class Book{
     protected $name;
     public function __construct($name){
        $this->name = $name;
     }
 }
class Requests
{
    protected $bookRequested;
    protected $reader;
    protected $requestDate;
    protected $returnDate;

    public function __construct(Book $bookRequested, Reader $reader)
    {
        $this->bookRequested = $bookRequested;
        $this->reader = $reader;
        $this->requestDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $this->returnDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }
    public function validate(){
        echo get_class($this->reader);
    }
}
 $teacher = new Teacher();
 $student = new Student();
 $gen_pu = new GeneralPublic();

 $book = new Book("Travel");
 $req = new Requests($book,$teacher);
$req->validate();
```